# Software to simulate molten salt flow and thermodynamic operations

Tags: pde, computational-chemistry, software-recommendation

I was curious if there was any software (preferably in C++, Java, and/or python) that could be used to simulate the following:

Heat capacity of a fluid
Heat transfer through a liquid and a solid
specific heat
molten salt flow as a liquid
operating temperatures for salt around 600 C
Effectively, this is simulating the chemistry and thermodynamics parts of a molten salt reactor.

Any price range will do, however, cheaper programs (even if they do have to cut out some of the more complicated processes) are preferred.

EDIT: Link to related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/497077/software-to-simulate-molten-salt-flow-and-thermodynamic-operations

Comment: I am not an expert at all in this topic. However, COMSOL would be one of the commonly used tools for multiphysics. How does [this](https://www.comsol.com/paper/electrical-and-bubbly-flow-modeling-of-a-molten-salt-electrolysis-cell-40791) correspond to what you are actually looking for?

Comment: What is the model you want to solve? The Navier-Stokes equations (plus temperature equations) for high-speed flow, or is the Stokes equation sufficient? How large are the temperature variations? Sufficient that you need to consider the density a variable?

Comment: @Anton Menshov that is what I am looking for, but if the software might also be extended to heat transfer onto other surfaces through a heat exchanger.

Comment: @Wolfgang Bangerth the Navier-Strokes equation will be needed in addition to any basic concepts surrounding heat capacity, temperature changes in the salt given a certain amount of radioactive decay, directionality of the molten salt flow at around 0.5 m/s, and systems that can operate between 20 degrees C and 600 degrees C with density of salt changing accordingly.

Comment: @KyleKanos Info added; any software advice?

Comment: @SuperNerdsTeam, that info should be in the question instead of being on the comments.

Comment: I have seen [Fluent](https://www.ansys.com/products/fluids/ansys-fluent) for molten salt in thermocline tanks. Check these two references:

["Short and long-term sensitivity thermocline thermal storage"](https://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1313&context=coolingpubs) Applied Thermal Engineering 109 (2016): 936-948.

["Comparative analysis of single-and dual-media thermocline."](https://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1247&context=coolingpubs) Journal of Solar Energy Engineering 137.3 (2015): 031012.

Comment: Just a question, isn't there some non-local terms to be expected? When you have radiative heating, you would have to integrate some sourrounding volumes radiative output to determine local heating. Again, how detailed do you want to model the physics of it?

Comment: @MPIchael Basically on the level of Fluent. It is not professionally building a reactor, only getting simulations to run how the molten salt will flow and how heat will transfer. It would be cool to have a program where you could change the types of salts used (and their concentrations) and see how the salt and products will react with the materials that make up the reactor (corrosion), however this is not necessary. If you do happen to know of a program that can run all of this, I would be very interested in hearing about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I will convert my comment to an answer.

One of the commonly used simulation tools for multiphysics is [Comsol](https://www.comsol.com/). It would allow you to tie the simulations from different modules into one multiphysics model using a relatively simple GUI and allow for postprocessing & visualization.

In particular, [this paper](https://www.comsol.com/paper/electrical-and-bubbly-flow-modeling-of-a-molten-salt-electrolysis-cell-40791) describes the electrical and bubbly flow simulation of the molten salt, which you could augment with the heat transfer using [Comsol Heat Transfer module](https://www.comsol.com/heat-transfer-module). Comsol also holds technical conferences (the paper I linked is an example), where you can find a lot of hints on multiphysics modeling. I bet, there are other molten salt simulations with Comsol papers out there.

If you want to look for alternatives, you would have to know much more about your simulations and the mathematics behind the appropriate models. It is quite possible that you would be able to build your simulation using [FEniCS](https://fenicsproject.org/tutorial/), or some other alternatives, but that would require you to figure out the math behind first, and then assemble it – there will not be any cutting corners in this route.